# Hide Filename in Python's PDB

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, pdb

When using [PDB](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), Python's debugging tool, the current file name is printed at each step. Both the file name, and the current line, of course. However, it's too clunky for my taste. I'm only interested in printing the current line.

**How does one prevent the file name being printed every time?**

Note: More than happy to hear about solutions for [PDB++](https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/) if not possible with simple PDB!

Comment: Getting a fair bit of views but no upvotes. Fairly new to asking so please let me know what I can do to improve it!

Comment: That's just the way it is, unless you want to dive into `pdb.py` and hack it yourself. Using `pdb++`, you can always set the color of the filename to be the same color as your background, and viola! No more filename!